# Django - Inheriting particular ManyToManyField for each child class

Tags: django, inheritance, manytomanyfield

Here is what I would like to do; be able to inherit a ManyToManyField from an abstract class and get this ManyToManyField specific to each child with its own intermediate table. Is it possible ? because with this code i got errors... thank you.

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Mother(models.model):
    places = models.ManyToManyField(Place, through='%(class)s_Place', related="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related_place"
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Child1(Mother):
    pass

class Child2(Mother):
    pass

class Child1_Place(models.Model):
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place)
    child = models.ForeignKey(Child1)

class Child2_Place(models.Model):
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place)
    child = models.ForeignKey(Child2)
```

Comment: `places = models.ManyToManyField(Place, ...` without the 's'?

Comment: sorry, didn't get it ...